# Помогите реализовать идею с последовательным запуском

Tags: python, python-3.x

Накидал не большой код. В нем есть ошибка, `schedule` не видит переменную `a`.
Идея такова, что как только `task` завершается, появляется временная метка, которая летит прямиком в `schedule` и запускает `task2`
Можно ли таким способом реализовать?

```
import schedule
import time

class B:
    def task2(self):
        print("Вызов функции от проверки task")

class A:
    def task():
        print("Начало проверки")
        ...
        global a 
        a = time.strftime('\"%H:%M\"') #временная метка, для запуска task2 
        print(f"Проверка завершена в {a}")

def main():
    bot = A()
    bot2 = B()
    schedule.every().day.at("21:13").do(bot.task)
    schedule.every().day.at(a).do(bot2.task2)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Библиотека `schedul` не поддерживает динамическое планирование заданий в реальном времени на сколько я знаю. Мне кажется тут нужна более сложная система планирования, возможно, с использованием многопоточности или асинхронности

Comment: А вообще есть возможность вывести время завершения проверки? 
к примеру хочу чтобы условие выполнялось тогда, когда проверка закончилась

К примеру, if strftime >= (время завершения): делай дело